# Python - multiple %s string

Tags: python, string

how do you use multiple %s in a python output?

```
TEXT = 'Hi, your first name is %s' %Fname
```

This works fine but...

```
TEXT = 'Hi, your first name is %s and your last name is %s' %Fname %Lname
```

I get the error

```
TypeError: not enough arguments for format string
```

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Use a tuple:

```
TEXT = 'Hi, your first name is %s and your last name is %s' % (Fname, Lname)
```

Better: use [`str.format(*args, **kwargs)`](https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/stdtypes.html#str.format).

```
"Hi, your first name is {0} and your last name is {1}".format("foo", "bar")
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to use tuples:

```
TEXT = 'Hi, your first name is %s', % (Fname)
TEXT = 'Hi, your first name is %s and your last name is %s' % (Fname, Lname)
```

Also, consider using [`format()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string-formatting).

Answer (score 1):

```
TEXT = 'Hi, your first name is %s and your last name is %s' %(Fname, Lname)
```

or

```
TEXT ='Hi, your first name is {} and your last name is {}'.format(Fname, Lname)
```

Comment: Both is not valid Python.

Comment: Syntex mistake in ", %(Fname, Lname)" and right one is  %(Fname, Lname)

Answer (score 1):

I like using string format instead.

So

```
TEXT = 'Hi, your first name is {} and your last name is {}'.format(Fname, Lname)
```

Answer (score 1):

Give all the variables in a tuple, like this:

```
TEXT = 'Hi, your first name is %s and your last name is %s.' %(Fname,Lname)
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is print:

```
print ('Hi, my name is %s ,i %s' % (objectName, targetName))
```